# Create a varSelectInput from a specific columns

Tags: r, shinyapps

I have this data set `ao_summary`

```
            full_name matches gender aces double_faults bp_won_pctg highlight
1    Alexander Zverev       5      M   86            21          22      TRUE
2     Aryna Sabalenka       4      F   20            17          19     FALSE
3      Ashleigh Barty       5      F   24            15          23     FALSE
4      Aslan Karatsev       6      M   54            20          34     FALSE
5     Daniil Medvedev       7      M   80            21          37     FALSE
6         Donna Vekic       4      F   15            19          18     FALSE
7     Grigor Dimitrov       5      M   51            14          23     FALSE
8      Jennifer Brady       7      F   34            17          29     FALSE
9    Karolina Muchova       6      F   17            13          29     FALSE
10  Karolina Pliskova       3      F   19            16          15     FALSE
11       Milos Raonic       4      M   82            16          17     FALSE
12        Naomi Osaka       7      F   50            22          29     FALSE
13     Novak Djokovic       7      M  103            23          37     FALSE
14    Serena Williams       6      F   35            16          27     FALSE
15 Stefanos Tsitsipas       6      M   46            17          22     FALSE
```

I would like to create a varSelectInput for the `full_name` column, being able to select the player name from the list, how would I do that?

I tried:

```
renderUI ({
    varSelectInput(
      inputId = "PlayerName", 
      label = "Select Player", 
      data = the_data()[, c("full_name")], 
      selected = "Novak Djokovic"
    )
  })
```

`the_data()` is the reactive data created in the server.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you actually want `selectInput` with `choices =`

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    uiOutput('select')
        )
server <- function(input, output) {
ao_summary <- reactiveVal()
ao_summary(structure(list(full_name = c("Alexander Zverev", "Aryna Sabalenka", 
                                         "Ashleigh Barty", "Aslan Karatsev", "Daniil Medvedev", "Donna Vekic", 
                                         "Grigor Dimitrov", "Jennifer Brady", "Karolina Muchova", "Karolina Pliskova", 
                                         "Milos Raonic", "Naomi Osaka", "Novak Djokovic", "Serena Williams", 
                                         "Stefanos Tsitsipas"), matches = c(5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 5L,
                                         7L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L), gender = c("M", "F", "F", "M", 
                                         "M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M"), aces = c(86L, 
                                         20L, 24L, 54L, 80L, 15L, 51L, 34L, 17L, 19L, 82L, 50L, 103L, 
                                         35L, 46L), double_faults = c(21L, 17L, 15L, 20L, 21L, 19L, 14L, 
                                         17L, 13L, 16L, 16L, 22L, 23L, 16L, 17L), bp_won_pctg = c(22L, 
                                         19L, 23L, 34L, 37L, 18L, 23L, 29L, 29L, 15L, 17L, 29L, 37L, 27L, 
                                         22L), highlight = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
                                         FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
                                         )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
                                         "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15")))
output$select <- renderUI({
    selectInput(
        inputId = "PlayerName", 
        label = "Select Player", 
        choices = ao_summary()[, c("full_name")], 
        selected = "Novak Djokovic"
    )
})   
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

The player name is then available in `input$PlayerName`.